# jquery apply rgb borders in element

Tags: jquery, css

I want to modify the border of the *arrow*-element with jQuery, but it won't get modified.
But it works fine with CSS.

HTML>>

```
    <div class="pointer">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <div class="arrow_border"></div>
    </div>
```

JQUERY>>

```
    $('.arrow_border').css({'border':'rgb(0, 0, 0, 0) rgb(rgb(219, 0, 219) rgb(0, 0, 0) rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;'});
    $('.arrow_border').css({'border-color':'rgb(0, 0, 0, 0) rgb(rgb(219, 0, 219) rgb(0, 0, 0) rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;'});
```

CSS >>

```
    .arrow, .arrow_border {
        border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgb(80, 255, 255) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        border-width: 11px;
        border-style: solid;
        font-size: 0;
        left: 50%;
        line-height: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 0;
        z-index: 1002;
        left: 0;
        margin-left: 45%;
    }
```

Comment: html has class "arrow", in jquery you going to class "pointer" and your css has class "arrow_border" could you please show the right parts and maybe also create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @caramba check it 
http://jsfiddle.net/vjaJg/

Comment: i checked it: less code does the same: http://jsfiddle.net/vjaJg/1/ so I still don't know why so much markup and different classes...

Comment: @caramba look at top of my question, i want to change border-color of that bullet in jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting style properties using JavaScript is not exactly the same as using CSS.

You can still use string property names in jQuery but I would recommend using the JavaScript equivalent properties. e.g. `borderColor` instead of `'border-color'`. jQuery  translates it for you but any translation makes your script slower.

`!important` will not work in JavaScript because it's not an actual value. There are ways but I wouldn't go there. It's also completely unnecessary because it already has higher precedence than anything in the stylesheet. ([specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/))

Setting border will override every property set before in css. You should override as specific as possible. In this case you should use:

```
$('.arrow_border').css({
  borderRightColor: 'rgb(219, 0, 219)'
});
```

If you were to set the border property, you also have to include border widths and border styles again. This is the same behaviour as in CSS (files).

Answer (score 0):

Verry nice explained from René you should read that and if you want to set many properties it should look something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vjaJg/3/

```
$('.arrow_border').css({
    'borderRightColor'   : 'rgba(120,255,255,0.9)',
    'borderLeftColor'    : 'rgba(255,120,255,0.9)',
    'borderTopColor'     : 'rgba(255,255,120,0.9)',
    'borderBottomColor'  : 'rgba(120,255,255,0.9)'
});
```